# PHP MySQL JSON Login System

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm currently working on a login system (which works great by using two text fields and the user is then redirected). However, as I am developing a mobile app, it would be much easier to do this in JSON, and I am not entirely sure where to start. What I am basically looking to do is to use a https post request (from my app) so it would request: https://www.example.com/login.php?username=username&password=password

I have created a basic sample, but it's not what I'm looking to do with regards to passing in a parameter via the URL as my code just currently looks for users in the MySQL database and outputs the users in JSON. What I want to be able to do is pass in the username & password parameters, via the URL, and then output a "success" or "error" JSON response if the username/password is in the database or not.

```
<?php
$host     = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$db_name  = "test";
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");
$sql    = "select * from test_table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json   = array();
if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
       {
    $json['items'] = $row;
       }
    }
mysql_close($db_name);
echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

**Edit**

I have now started working on another system, which is pretty much what I am looking to do (after I found an example here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/235556-how-to-create-a-php-login-with-data-from-mysql-database/) except every time that I request something like https://www.example.com/login.php?username=root&password=password - I get the JSON error 1 code

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; // Host name
$db_username = "root"; // Mysql username
$db_password = "password"; // Mysql password
$db_name = "test"; // Database name
$tbl_name = "test_table"; // Table name

// Connect to server

mysql_connect("$host", "$db_username", "$db_password") or die("cannot connect");

// Select the database

mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");

// Get the login credentials from user

$username = $_POST['username'];
$userpassword = $_POST['password'];

// Secure the credentials

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$userpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

// Check the users input against the DB.

$query = "SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE user = '$username' AND password = '$userpassword'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because " . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row['total'] == 1) {

    // success

    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response

    echo json_encode($response);
}
else {

    // username and password not found
    // failed

    $response["failed"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response

    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Comment: Note that for an HTTP POST, one would typically use form parameters rather than query string parameters.

Comment: @maytham I have now edited my original code for improved functionality and security but currently getting an error

Comment: @maytham here's the form: http://codeshare.io/ETRcX & here's the above code for generating a JSON response: http://codeshare.io/SERMM - what I am essentially looking to do is somehow securely pass username & password (as parameters) into the URL > make a MySQL check to see if the username/password is in the database > if it's in the db then a JSON "success" string should be echoed and if it's not in the db, then a JSON "failed" string should echoed

Comment: @TobyClench Can you copy exactly the hole error content.

Comment: @maytham I'm not getting any error with the PHP script that outputs the JSON string; it just always outputs the JSON error response rather than the JSON success response so (even though the username & password are in the database) it will output: {"failed":1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change following lines and it should works. I get it to work, as the way you describe it.

1- Here you will get URL parameters and sanitize.

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$userpassword = $_GET['password'];

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$userpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($userpassword);
```

2- Here you count how many rows you have

Change `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`

to `$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);`

3- Here you check if you have at least 1 row.

And change `if ($row['total'] == 1) {` to `if ($total_rows == 1) {`

That should give output `{"success":1}`

**Note1:** This is to solve your request and question, but does not necessary means the right approach or perfect solution in general.

**Note2:** I would suggest you think of password hashing, post method in stead of get, use mysqli or PDO in sted of mysql and input sensitization and not use URL to pass username and password. I would suggest you look at this [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) it describes some of the things I mentioned in my note1.

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: Still resulting in the {"failed":1} for me, even after making the changes that you suggested. Maybe it's something to do with the row count?

Comment: Okay thanks but after putting in a few echos (to check the query, result & row) the query is correct and is getting the username & password passed into it (thanks to your suggested code change); the result finds the user details in the database and there's only ever one row returned which leads me onto believing that something is wrong with the way in which the row is being counted

Comment: It means that, I think, I have found the issue as to why it always returns as failed. So, how else would I go about counting the number of rows that the query generates?

Comment: and your link https://www.example.com/login.php?myusername=root&mypassword=password should https://www.example.com/login.php?username=usernameInFromDatabase&password=passwordInFromDatabase

Comment: That would be why it always goes to the failed response but this is the MySQL database setup: http://codeshare.io/Bzlpq & about the username and password, that is correct: I am using the username and password that's been added to the database

Comment: Just implemented your edited answer and it works a treat! Seriously didn't realize that the change was that simple; thank you for your help. You also mentioned previously about whether this was for learning or for work: what was the reasoning? As it's being used for learning but also to work within an application

Comment: Okay, how would I go about implementing password hashing? As improving the security of this logging in functionality is important

Comment: Okay - thank you for all of your help with learning and understanding this

Comment: Made the relevant changes, marked as answered and upvoted as being a helpful answer

Comment: check the link I added it and try work on it as next phase you can learn more.

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for to improve security measures; thanks again